# Returned Service Value always Undefined inside Controller?

Tags: angularjs

Simply put, i have a Poller that returns msgdata and newdata variables based on conditions however the returned value in this case is always undefined. The Conditions should be overriding the initial variable initialising correct inside the service?

How can i get the Poller.msgdata and Poller.newdata to Return the TRUE or FALSE to the controller?

Controller:

```
app.controller('sidemenuController', ['$scope', 'projectsModal', 'sendMessageModal', 'Poller', '$timeout',  
    function($scope, projectsModal, sendMessageModal, Poller, $timeout) {

    var update = function() {
    $timeout(update, 5000);
        $scope.inbox = Poller.msgdata;
        $scope.project = Poller.newdata;
        console.log("Updated SideMenu Controller: " + Poller.msgdata);
    }
    update();

    $scope.projects = Poller.projects;
    $scope.messages = Poller.messages;

    $scope.sendMessage = sendMessageModal.activate;
    $scope.showModal = function() {
        projectsModal.deactivate();
        projectsModal.activate();
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked
        projectsModal.deactivate();
        sendMessageModal.deactivate();
    }

}]);
```

Service:

```
app.factory('Poller', Poller);
Poller.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];

function Poller($http, $timeout) {

var projectcache = { response: [], calls: 0 };
var msgcache = { response: [], calls: 0 };
var newdata;
var msgdata;

var poller = function () {
  $timeout(poller, 5000);
   $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php')
   .then(function(r) {
     if (r.data.projects.length > projectcache.response.length) {
      newdata = true;
      angular.copy(r.data.projects, projectcache.response);
     } else {
      newdata = false;
     };
     console.log(msgdata);
   });
   $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getMessages.php')
   .then(function(m) {
     if (m.data.messages.length > msgcache.response.length) {
      msgdata = true;
      angular.copy(m.data.messages, msgcache.response);
     } else {
      msgdata = false;
     };
   });
};
poller();

return {
  projects: projectcache.response,
  messages: msgcache.response,
  newdata: newdata,
  msgdata: msgdata
};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your polling method reassigns the local variables `newdata` and `msgdata`, but it doesn't reassign the fields of the object returned by the service, which are initialized to undefined and never modified after.

You need to keep a reference to the returned object in a variable:

```
var service = { ... };
...
return service;
```

and in the polling method, change the values inside the service:

```
service.newdata = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
return {
  projects: projectcache.response,
  messages: msgcache.response,
  newdata: newdata,
  msgdata: msgdata
};
```

The data you get from Poller.newdata should always be the initial value of var newdata, because javascript do not pass by reference.

projects and messages work because you are doing angular.copy, which keeps the same reference.

An easy way to fix this would be passing back an object instead of boolean itself

```
var checkNew = {};
```

in poller function

```
checkNew.newdata = true;
```

in return

```
checkNew: checkNew
```

in controller

```
$scope.inbox = Poller.checkNew.msgdata;
$scope.project = Poller.checkNew.newdata;
```

---

A cleaner way (imo) to do this would be exposing the poller function as a service function to the controller. By this way you don't need to have a timeout on the service, it gets data whenever the controller calls it.